# Blender object variables?

Tags: python, blender, mesh

So I've been developing an upcoming RPG and hit a block in blender. Specific meshes to represent the equipped item and how to show it... Like if I had twelve different helmets but only wanted to display one via python. All the while every helmet would be parented to the same bone but only one would be shown, and the rest hidden... Somethiiing like:

## init

helmetMesh = obj_helm1

## but is there something like:

hide_mesh(allHelmetMeshes)
show_mesh(helmetMesh)

## ?

Maybe there's already something like that I could implement? I looked online and saw no relevancies...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have each mesh object hidden during game play then use an [Edit Object Actuator](https://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/edit_object.html) to change the mesh used by the game object.

[image]

The python controller in the middle can be something like this -

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

kbd = cont.sensors["Keyboard"]

for key,status in kbd.events:
    if status == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
        if key == bge.events.FKEY:
            cont.activate(cont.actuators['ToCube'])
        elif key == bge.events.GKEY:
            cont.activate(cont.actuators['ToCone'])
        elif key == bge.events.HKEY:
            cont.activate(cont.actuators['ToSphere'])
```

Here's an example blend [image]
<sub>(source: [giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=869))</sub>